# How to detect an empty element of a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm getting a JSON response after an AJAX call. The response contains some elements like id, name, number, etc. The method return sometimes just the id and the number, in other cases the id, the name and the number. In the success part of the AJAX, JQuery method I'm testing if I'm getting the right keys . When a key like name dosen't exists I'm getting an error : `Cannot read property 'name' of null`. It's clear that's i have a problem in my if condition.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "edit_info",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'id': id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.name) {
          console.log(data.name);
      }
});
```

So any alternative

Comment: @Mir Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)

Comment: `Cannot read property 'name' of null` I am sure it would be `undefined` not `null`.

Comment: data is undefined as mentioned in error msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting `Cannot read property 'name' of null`, means your `data` object is `null`

You can check for falsy value

```
if(data && data.name){
    console.log(data.name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` allows the identifier to never have been declared before.

```
if (typeof data.name != "undefined" && data.name.trim().length) {
     console.log(data.name);
}
```

Comment: It may so happen that `data.name` contain only white space. so we need trim()

Comment: if it has something like ' ' ie space as data. To avoid that

Comment: but name value can be an empty string.

Comment: it's working but without the second part `data.name.trim().length`

Comment: @KubiRoazhon its always good to use this `data.name.trim().length` when you check for empty sting

Answer (score 0):

use typeof operator

```
if(typeof data.name!='undefined')
{
    console.log(data.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery give you [length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) function for the task

```
if ( data.length != 0 ){
    console.log(data.name);
}
```

Comment: well this will fail.. it will throw error  like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)`